# How to get the Path of current selected file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to get the path of current selected file in Eclipse workspace but **my project is a simple view plug-in project.**

I just want to display the name/path of the file selected as soon as user opens the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the current selection as mentioned by @Danail Nachev.  See http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html for information on working with the selection service.

Once you have the selection, the most common pattern is:

```
    if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
        IStructuredSelection ssel = (IStructuredSelection) selection;
        Object obj = ssel.getFirstElement();
        IFile file = (IFile) Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(obj,
                IFile.class);
        if (file == null) {
            if (obj instanceof IAdaptable) {
                file = (IFile) ((IAdaptable) obj).getAdapter(IFile.class);
            }
        }
        if (file != null) {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

Edit:

Usually you get an `InputStream` from the `IFile` and process it that way.  Using some FileSystemProviders or EFS implementations, there might not be a local path to the file.

PW

Comment: I am getting the output as L/rcp/MyXML.xml. How to avoid this L and add the raw/absolute path of the file.

Comment: Read the API for IFile and IResource.  it has methods to get the absolute filesystem path.

Comment: these are terrible indirect answers... see here for a direct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900124/eclipse-plugin-get-code-from-current-open-file

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the current workbench selection <strike>using two methods</strike> with the following code:

1. through the Workbench [SelectionService](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html)
2. `getViewSite().getSelectionProvider().getSelection()`

`getViewSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService()`

You can find more information in [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html).

Using the global workbench selection is the better approach, because it enables your view to get selection from everywhere, which is something the user might expect (I at least do). Also, almost all of the views in Eclipse (and I don't know exceptions to this rule) are using this approach.

If you absolutely must to tie your view to another view, then you can get all `IWorkbenchPage` iterate over them and search for the view by its ID and when you find the view, you call get its `SelectionProvider` to get the selection.

Only by reading this explanation, makes my hair go straight up. Considering that there might be multiple instances of the same view, you can end up with a selection from a random view. I'm not sure whether the user will make sense of how things work, unless you have some clear rules, which exactly view you need. It is up to you.

`

Comment: But the question is - how do you get the path of the selected file (presumably from the Project explorer view, OP didn't specify)?

Comment: @Sandman - I've updated the answer, because it wasn't fully correct. About the path of the selected file, you can use the following methods IResource.getLocation(), IPath.toOSString(), IPath.toFile(). These methods should give a starting point as @Paul Webster mentioned.