# Eclipse RCP - project selected (Package Explorer)

Tags: eclipse, rcp

How do I retrieve the name and path of the project selected? (Package Explorer)

example: c:\project\test\projectName

---

someone has some code that explains how to complete I get the project name or full path of a particular project in my workspace?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse defines an extension point
**"org.eclipse.ui.navigator.linkHelper"**

If you contribute a class to these EP you have to implement **[ILinkHelper](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/navigator/ILinkHelper.html)**

The ILInkHelper interface notifies you, when something was selected in the explorer

- public void activateEditor(IWorkbenchPage aPage, IStructuredSelection aSelection)

You can check the type of the selection

```
 if (aSelection.getFirstElement() instanceof IFile) {
    // Do something
 }
```

Comment: \o/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183366/how-to-get-the-path-of-current-selected-file-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Old memories but maybe useful for you. I guess package explorer provides its selection, so you can get the current selection in your code by calling:

ISelectionService service = getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService()

than you can get the package explorer view by its id (plugin.xml for more details):

IStructuredSelection selection =  (IStructuredSelection) service.getSelection("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer");

Please note AFAIK you can always safely cast ISelection to IStructuredSelection. Then call structured.getFirstElement() and I think the first element will be an IFile object. I hope my "pseudo code" whould be enough for you. And IFile has lots of usefule methods for your convenience

Comment: IWorkbenchPart, but the main concept is try to get the selectionprovider service

Comment: I need something that I return a IProject.

exemple: myIproject.getName();

Comment: `getFirstElement()` will return an IProject if that is what is selected.