# Eclipse Plugin Get Code from Current Open File

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How can I get the code from the current open file in Eclipse returned in a `String` or `String[]`? I need this for a plugin I'm making.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

If I have HelloWorld.java open, how do I get that code returned in a `String[]`? The `String[]` would contain:

- "public class HelloWorld {"
- "public static void main(String[] args) {"
- "System.out.println("Hello, world!");"
- "}"
- "}"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the currently edited file's content you can do something like that:

```
IWorkbenchPart workbenchPart = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart(); 
IFile file = (IFile) workbenchPart.getSite().getPage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);
if (file == null) throw new FileNotFoundException();
String content = IOUtils.toString(file.getContents(), file.getCharset());
```

Comment: `The method getAdapter(Class<IFile>) is undefined for the type IEditorInput`

Comment: Also no class IFile and IOUtils.

Comment: IEditorInput implements the IAdaptable interface, so getAdapter() should be there.
IFile is in org.eclipse.core.resources.
IOUtils is a class in Apache Common libraries. You can convert the InputStream to a String using others methods if you prefer.

Which version of Eclipse are you using/targeting ?

Comment: To add "org.eclipse.core.resources", import is NOT enough. You have to add it as a dependency in your plugin MANIFEST.MF

Comment: There is nothing to download, you already have it (it a basic component of Eclipse). Add it in the MANIFEST.MF `Require-Bundle` list. (this code snippet is working for indigo.)

Comment: This code does get the **file content** —which is what was asked for. In some cases, one might want the **editor content**, instead —that would be a different question, though. In both cases, there is the presumption that "code" means **text**, but, in general, neither a file nor editor necessarily have text.