# IntelliJ Plugin Get Code From Current Open File

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Basically, I want to know how to do this ([Eclipse Plugin Get Code from Current Open File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900124/eclipse-plugin-get-code-from-current-open-file/17901551#17901551)) in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In what context? If you are inside an action, you can simply take everything from the ActionEvent, for example:

```
e.getData(LangDataKeys.EDITOR).getDocument().getText();
```

(When e is AnActionEvent).

Otherwise, you can get it from the project:

```
FileEditorManager.getInstance(project).getSelectedTextEditor().getDocument().getText();
```

Answer (score 16):

Just in case somebody is looking for this - if you want the **file name** of the currently open file, you have to jump through some additional hoops:

```
Document currentDoc = FileEditorManager.getInstance(project).getSelectedTextEditor().getDocument();
VirtualFile currentFile = FileDocumentManager.getInstance().getFile(currentDoc);
String fileName = currentFile.getPath()
```

(found this by entering "getSelectedTextEditor filename" in Github search - sometimes all you need is a pointer in the right direction...)

Comment: I'm kind of trying to do the same, but fail on getting project: `public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {  Project project = e.getProject(); ...` - it is null, somehow. What am I doing wrong?