# Get file path after selection of an object

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, selection

I am writing a simple Eclipse-plugin that displays a UI after right-mouse click on a specific element, located inside an xml file. In the handler, i need to get first the file path, which contains the selected object. I tried the following posts unfortunately did not work for me.

[How to get the Path of current selected file in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183366/how-to-get-the-path-of-current-selected-file-in-eclipse)

```
IFile file = (IFile) Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(obj,
            IFile.class);
```

[Eclipse Plugin Get Code from Current Open File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900124/eclipse-plugin-get-code-from-current-open-file)

```
IFile file = (IFile) workbenchPart.getSite().getPage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);
```

note: the file need not be opened in active editor.

Comment: What is the selected object, and how did you obtain it? What happens instead of what you expected?

Comment: Tnx @nitind, the selected object is of type EObject from Ecore, selected using ` IStructuredSelection ssel = (IStructuredSelection) selection;
           Object obj = ssel.getFirstElement();`       The file returns null in the first approach and returns the active file in the second approach. Note: i want to get the file path regardless of active or not, but only on the object selected.

Answer (score 1):

you need to retrieve the EResource from the EObject.
Please note that EObject might be in-memory and in this case there is no EResource/File associated with it.

See https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=796431&goto=1404419&#msg_1404419

Regards,