# Get File from ITreeSelection

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I currently develop a Eclipse Plug-in. Therefore I need to know the currently selected File in the Project (not in runtime Environment). Till now I get the selection from Eclipse and I know that the selection is a File (from debugger). But when I check if it is really a File it doesn't work.

```
ISelection selection = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
                                 .getActivePage().getSelection();
if (selection instanceof ITreeSelection) {
  ITreeSelection treeSelection = (ITreeSelection) selection;
  Object firstElement = treeSelection.getFirstElement();  //This Object is a File
  if (firstElement instanceof File) {
    File file = (File) firstElement;
    String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    String path = file.getPath();
    System.out.println("");
  }
}
```

When I debug the code it steps over the `instanceof` block. What am I doing wrong? I want to step into the Block.

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.println(firstElement.getClass())` ?

Comment: It's `class org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File`

Comment: Try `intanceof iFile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is find out if it is an instance of Adaptable.

```
if (firstElement instanceof IAdaptable) {
     file = (IFile) ((IAdaptable) firstElement).getAdapter(IFile.class);
}
```

Have a look at [How to get the Path of current selected file in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183366/how-to-get-the-path-of-current-selected-file-in-eclipse)