# Get the fullpath of current file in Eclipse Plugin - FileEditorInput not found

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to get the path of the current open file in Eclipse.

I tried to use this portion of code:

```
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorInput;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;

IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IWorkbenchWindow window = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();
IPath path = ((FileEditorInput)input).getPath();
```

but the problem is that I get the compile error

```
FileEditorInput cannot be resolved to a type
```

How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183366/how-to-get-the-path-of-current-selected-file-in-eclipse

Comment: What means 'FileEditorInput is not available'?

Comment: Use `IFileEditorInput`.

Comment: Irrespective of your problem, you should use `input.getAdapter( IFile.class )` if you want to know which `IFile` is being edited. This also covers cases where another editor input than `IFileEditorInput` is used to represent an `IFile`. `getAdapter()` will return `null` if the current editor input has no file.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann The error is: FileEditorInput cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: @greg-449 if I use IFileEditorInput instead of FileEditorInput doesn't change anything. I also read about this solution but for me doesn't working

Comment: @JorgeS.Cortez I tried the solution that you suggest. I have not error in this case but it doesn't print nothing. Maybe because my program is a plugin and I run it as "Eclipse Application" ?

Comment: `IFileEditorInput` is exported by `org.eclipse.ui.ide`. Did you declare a dependency on this plug-in?

Comment: This code has to be in a plugin so that is not the problem. 'Cannot be resolved as a type' usually means you are missing dependencies in your MANIFEST.MF

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Yes, I added the dependencies of org.eclipse.ui.ide in my MANIFEST.MF

Comment: ... and the version range matches the one of the plug-in in your target platform?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann I don't know how check this. Meanwhile I found what to import: org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput; but how can see the filepath? I tried print or save it in a file but I haven't anything in output

Comment: What exactly are you trying to print or save in a file?

Comment: I am trying to print path.toString() or path.getName(), but their value was null

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente ce l'ho fatta.

ecco il codice funzionante:

```
import org.eclipse.ui.IFileEditorInput;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorInput;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;


IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IWorkbenchWindow window = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();
IPath path = ((IFileEditorInput)input).getFile().getFullPath();
File myFile = path.toFile();
```